# Bike Rack (w/hitch) - Any easy-to-remove anti-wobble bolts/pins?

Tags: rack, transportation

I've just purchased a hitch for my car and the Allen S535 bike rack.  It comes with an anti-wobble bolt that is screwed onto the hitch but it is very time consuming when I need to remove the rack off the car.

Is there any solution besides using the anti-wobble nut/bolt?

Comment: Ride your bike and leave the car at home ?

Answer (score 1):

For my Allen rack, I decided against using that bolt.  My hitch has 2 holes in it for securing, and the smaller one is the same size as the bike rack.  I ended up just getting a locking hitch pin from a local store and it works fine.  I believe that the pin I got had a sleeve that fit over it for the larger, more commonly used hole.